# SQLite Viewers/Browsers prevention in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I need to know how to secure my `sqlite` database file from being edited or adding records to by `sqlite` viewers/browsers, I am using c#

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I worked around it and used `System.Data.Sqlite` to encrypt the database using these methods

```
void EncryptDB()
{
    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Test.db;Password="))
    {
        conn.Open();
        conn.ChangePassword("password");
        conn.Close();
    }
}

void DecryptDB()
{
    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Test.db;Password=password"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        conn.ChangePassword("");
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I call the `DecryptDB()` method before I connect to the database with `sqlite-net-pcl` and I call `EncryptDB()` after the connection is closed.

If you are asking why I didn't use `System.Data.Sqlite` instead of `sqlite-net-pcl`, that is because I found that `sqlite-net-pcl` is neat and less code is needed to perform the task which makes it easier to read and document.

@MikeT Thank you for your answer it really guided me and helped me reach this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SQLite Encryption Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/index.wiki) the database could then not be opened as an SQLite database without the key.

An alternative would be to simulate how SEE works. That is that the data stored on the disk is always fully encrypted by your favourite encryption method and that the database is decrypted to a temporary file and then opened (obviously only when the correct key is provided) when accessing the database, it then being encrypted and written when done with.

Another alternative would be to utilise [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but those are paid libraries and I need a free solution.